# if statement doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm a newbie in JQuery, but I just can't find out why the if statement here doest work. You see in the code `alert(a)` and `alert(timesRun)` I put it there so i could test, if the variables did indeed count up as intended and they did.

Now is the problem: var a is determined by userinput and should make the clock stop when its equal to timesrun but the if statement seems not to work even when both alerts say: `var a =12` and `var timesrun is 12` the interval continues even though the if statement should have stopped it. Sorry if I'm being unclear or messy I am just at secondary school and not even native English speaker.

```
< script >
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#turnright1').click(function () {
      var a = $("#nummr1").val();
      var angle = 0;
      var timesRun = 0;
      var interval = setInterval(function () {
        timesRun += 1;
        alert(a);
        alert(timesRun);

        if (timesRun === a) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }

        angle += 3.6;
        $('img[src^="Images/lockercenter.png"]').rotate(angle);
        i++
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted that helped you fix this, instead of editing question and saying: "This is fixed." That way other people can also see which was the thing that helped you along.

Comment: I know but stackoverflow didnt let me yet(had to wait 8 min) . Also im new to the site but i get it now.

Comment: Ah, ok. No worries then. :) Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$("#nummr1").val();` returns a string, and you are checking for strict equality with `===`. To fix the problem, change it to

```
if(timesRun == a){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

`
or

```
if(timesRun === parseInt(a)){ //or +a;
        clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `===` operator, it checks for  the types of the operands as well.  `timesRun` is a `Number` while the value returned from the `val()` is a `String`.

You can either change the operator to `==` or parse the value using `parseInt` first

Answer (score 0):

It is because your are using triple equals (===) in the line

```
if (timesRun === a) {
```

in order for === to work, you need to have ensure that both "timesRun" and "a" are string, or both integer, but not a mix.

for example

```
if (String(timesRun) === String(a)) {
```

or

```
if (parseInt(timesRun, 10) === parseInt(a, 10)) {
```

will work. Don't use parseInt without the second parameter or you will have bad surprises.

```
if (timesRun == a) {
```

will also work here, but double equality can de considered dangerous in Javascript.